# Report (SSRS) on Oracle DataSource slow loading

Tags: oracle, performance, reporting-services, oracle11g, ssrs-2008

Report based on Oracle function. Info loading very slowly.
(Report based on SQL Server, stored procedure loads normal).

Query to load looks like this:

```
SELECT some_column
FROM TABLE (function_name(to_date(:date_b, "dd.MM.yyyy"), to_date(:date_e, "dd.MM.yyyy")))
```

Parameters set from report parameter

I try to set date

```
SELECT some_column
FROM TABLE (function_name(to_date("12.08.2019", "dd.MM.yyyy"), to_date("12.08.2019", "dd.MM.yyyy")))
```

but I don't get any results.

Is there any way to speed up report loading? (no access to change source)

Comment: If you can't change the source of the function it seems unlikely you'll be able to do any of the other tricks we might use to improve query performance - add (or remove) an index, gather fresh statistics, etc.